# How to use providedIn 'root' in angular service

Tags: javascript, css

How to use providedIn 'root' in angular service?

Comment: It is not possible. You will have to write some custom modal for that to work.

Comment: You can't. It's part of the browser's default UI. There are a plethora of plugins to accomplish this. Just do a search for "lightbox" or "modal"

Answer (score 2):

Style of `alert()` JS function is defined by the browser you are using. You can't change that.

But you can implement custom alert boxes using, for example, [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or other libraries.